# How can we drag and drop image inside scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application am having CustomScrollView subclass of UIScrollView (I am not using UIView here) in which I have 10 images at bottom and I want to drag any image from bottom to anywhere in scrollview by making copy of it and not deleting original at bottom. BY using touchEnd , touchMoved and touchBegan functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your touch begin method you will get touch points and will be able to get `imageView` where touch begin. Now if you want to show moving of image view do following:

- in touch begin get the `UIImageView` object
- create a new `UIImageView` object with same properties.

  ```
  UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myCurrentImageView.frame];
  newImageView.image = myCurrentImageView.image;
  //other properties if needed
  [myscrlview addSubView:newImageView];
  ```

  This will add image in your scroll view at same place your previous image view was.
- In touch move you will get your touch points
- set your any of `UIImageView` object lets say

  ```
  newImageView.center = touchPoint;
  ```

  this will show your image moving
- In `thouchEnd` do the same set your `newImageView` center at touch end position.

Make sure that you set your `UIScrollView` properties like content size and every thing as well while moving new image may have origin negative in case your center set to x=0, y=0.

This will keep the previous image as it is in scroll view and create a copy of new that image while moving.

Hope this is what you looking for. If not let me know.

**Note:** Code may have errors as I just typed here not in xcode but you can understand what to do